# Ndb cluster change variable for heartbeat and disconnect

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, ndbcluster

I search for a variable that I can increase in the server that I don't get any more this error:

Node 2 missed heartbeat 2
Node 3 Disconnected
Node 2 Disconnected

I don't find anything.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Configuration variable HeartbeatIntervalDbDb, see in manual:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-cluster-ndbd-definition.html#ndbparam-ndbd-heartbeatintervaldbdb